# How to navigate one page to another without changing state in Flutter using flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-android

I am facing one issue in which when I am going from one page to another page using **flitter BLoC**, my first page rebuild before reaching to second. I am able to restrict the rebuild of the page using **buildWhen** in **BlocBuilder**, but the problem is when I come back to the first page again by back press then the page can not show the previous state widgets. I don't know how to manage navigation between pages without rebuild the page again, I am using **flutter_bloc 6.1.1** below is my code.

## FirstPage

```
class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
final MyData dataObj;

FirstPage({this.dataObj});

@override
_MyFirstPageState createState() => _MyFirstPageState();
}

class _MyFirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {

FirstPageBloc _bloc = FirstPageBloc();
String _userAddress='';

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_bloc.add(UserInfoEvent(dataObj:widget.dataObj));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(StringConstants.APP_TITLE_HEADING),
    ),
    body: BlocListener<FirstPageBloc, FirstPageState>(
      cubit: _bloc,
      listenWhen: (previousState, state) {
        // return true/false to determine whether or not
        // to call listener with state

        return true;
      },
      listener: (context, state) async{
        if (state is LoadingState) {
          print('Loading ...');
        }
        if (state is DataInfoState) {
          _userAddress=state.userAddress;
        }
        if(state is ConfirmationState){
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(dataObj: widget.dataObj)));
        }

      },
      child: BlocBuilder<FirstPageBloc, FirstPageState>(
          //bloc: _bloc,
          cubit: _bloc,
          buildWhen: (previousState, state) {
            // return true/false to determine whether or not
            // to rebuild the widget with state
            if(state is ConfirmationState){
              return false;
            }
            return true;
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is LoadingState) {
              return Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor:
                    AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(ColorConstants.Primary),),
                    Text(StringConstants.PLEASE_WAIT)
                  ],),
              );
            }
            return _mainWidget();
          }),
     ),
  );
 }
}
```

## BLoC

```
 class FirstPageBloc extends Bloc<FirstPageEvent, FirstPageState>{

 FirstPageBloc() : super(InitialState());

 @override
 Stream<FirstPageState> mapEventToState(FirstPageEvent event) async*{

// TODO: implement mapEventToState
if(event is DataInfoEvent){
  yield* _getUserData(event.dataObj);
}
if(event is ConfirmationEvent){
  yield* _confirmTaskData(event.dataObj);
 }
}
 Stream<DelConfirmState> _confirmTaskData(MyData dataObj) async* {
  yield LoadingState();

  //Performing some SQLite DB operations

  yield ConfirmationState();

}
Stream<DelConfirmState> _getUserData(MyData dataObj) async* {

  yield LoadingState();
  String userAddress='ABDC001, PIN- 0091910, 5th Main USA';
  //Fetching User data from SQLite database and passing to UI

  yield DataInfoState(userAddress:userAddress);
 }
}
```

## State

```
  abstract class FirstPageState extends Equatable {}

 ///This is our initial state
 class InitialState extends FirstPageState {
 @override
 List<Object> get props => null;
 }

 //This state will call for loading the progress var
class LoadingState extends FirstPageState {
@override
List<Object> get props => [];
}

//This state will call for loading the progress var
class ErrorState extends FirstPageState {
final String errorMessage;

ErrorState({@required this.errorMessage});
@override
List<Object> get props => [];
}

//This state will retun the userdata
class DataInfoState extends FirstPageState {
final String userAddress;

DataInfoState({@required this.userAddress});

@override
// TODO: implement props
List<Object> get props => [];
}
class TaskConfirmationState extends FirstPageState {

ConfirmationState({});

@override
// TODO: implement props
List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

## Event

```
   abstract class FirstPageEvent extends Equatable {}

   class GetUserInfoEvent extends FirstPageEvent {
   final MyData dataObj;

   GetUserInfoEvent({this.taskObj});
   @override
   List<Object> get props => [];
  }
  class ConfirmationEvent extends FirstPageEvent {
  final MyData dataObj
  ConfirmationEvent({this.dataObj});
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
 }
```

Please advise
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your bloc at a higher level widget, then you need to get it from the context. In this way the state will persist even through navigation.
You can do that wrapping your widget like this:

```
BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => FirstPageBloc(),
      child: FirstPage(),
    )
```

and then inside of initState you can get it like this:

```
_bloc = BlocProvider.of<FirstPageBloc>(context);
```